# Concrete examples between Anonymous functions and regular functions

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and i'm trying to understand the real differences between those 3 syntaxes of code :

```
//first code
def add(x:Int, y:Int) = {x+y}
//second code
val add2 = (x:Int,y:Int) => x+y
//third code
def add3 = (x:Int,y:Int) => x+y
```

I can approximatively see the differences but I don't know which one should I use depends on the context.
Is anyone have concrete examples ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

This is a [**FAQ**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/index.html#whats-the-difference-between-methods-and-functions).
But, given you also asked when to use each I guess it is worth adding a little bit over that.

First, let's explain what does each mean:

1. Is a **method** of two arguments, both are **Int** and it returns another **Int**; as such, it is not a value.
2. Is a **function** of two arguments, both are **Ints** and it returns another **Int**; as such, it is a value whose type is `Function2[Int, Int, Int]` *(commonly known as `(Int, Int) => Int`)*.
3. Is a **method** of zero arguments, and it returns a **function** `(Int, Int) => Int`

In general always use the first one, since it is more powerful *(**Scala 3** will reduce the differences between **methods** and **functions**, but still)*, for most people the syntax is more clear, it should be more efficient. And, even if you are going to use it as a function, for example for a `map`, then *eta-expansion* will take care of that.
Use the second one when you are absolutely sure you need it as a **function**, for example you know you will be using things like `andThen` with other **functions**; this is not very common.
Never use the third one since it would be creating a new object every time you call it, to then discard it after its use *(which would be very inefficient)* and it should be the same as using `val` instead of `def`; the only *"valid"* reason for a **method** of no arguments that returns a **function**, would be that the function is always different but that would imply a side-effect that is discouraged.